# HTML form - wont update Mysql database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html, css

this is seriously confusing me.. I now have such a headache! I have been learning php for a month and this is the sort of stuff I expected to srtuggle with 4 weeks ago s:

I am recieving the warning Undefined index and the database is updating with the date 0000-00-00 and then nothing in the other column, i turned the query into an echo to see what was happening but nothing seems to be getting assigned to the variables that are being sent from the form!

The Code:
(simplified)

**calender.php**

```
<form name="slots" action="updatecalender.php" method="post">
Day: <input type="text" name="dayofmonth" />
<select name="month">
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">June</option>
    <option value="7">July</option>
    <option value="8">August</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
<select name="year">
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
    <option value="2020">2020</option>
    <option value="2021">2021</option>
    <option value="2022">2022</option>
    <option value="2023">2023</option>
</select><br /><br />
Slots Available:
<input type="text" name="noslots" /><br />
<input type="submit" value=" - Go - " />
</form>
```

**updatecalender.php**

```
<?php
//connect to database

require "dbconn.php";

$dayofmonth = $_GET['dayofmonth'];
$month = $_GET['month'];
$year = $_GET['year'];
$noslots = $_GET['noslots'];

$query = INSERT INTO calender VALUES ('".$year."-".$month."-".$dayofmonth."','".$noslots."')";

$results = mysql_query($query)
            or die(mysql_error());

header('Location:calender.php');

    ?>
```

I am a beginner so I am not playing with making it secure... just making it work!

Thank you soo much for any advice and help!

Comment: Is this really the code you're using?  The line beginning with `$query = ` looks like it would have at least one parser error.  Also, what does the resulting query look like?  You said you echoed it, can you share it?

Comment: your form uses POST, your PHP uses GET. Use $_POST

Comment: Oh look. Non-sanitised input. [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) will have so much fun. Is there a PHP/SQL tutorial anywhere on the planet that actually worries about SQL injection? "I am a beginner so I am not playing with making it secure" — So what? Security comes free with sane APIs. Use PDO. Don't use mysqli.

Comment: @mdi: Looks like you caught it first. You should post that as the answer.

Comment: sorry, I meant i echoed it so i could see if the variables had been assigned... and with regards the query, i missed in the code i copied into here a "    I am learning still though (obvs)

Comment: Thank you! **facepalm**

Thanks guys I really appreciate it!

Comment: @mdi please post this answer so I can give you the tick! [=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your form uses POST, your PHP uses GET. Use $_POST

(initially proposed in comments)

Answer (score 2):

Start by using $_POST in your php code i.e.:

```
$dayofmonth = $_POST['dayofmonth'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$noslots = $_POST['noslots'];
```

Also, consider learning `PDO`. Your code is not secure as it is. `PDO` will help sanitize your inputs and help prevent things such as SQL Injections

Answer (score 1):

this may work for you.

```
<?php 
    //connect to database 

    require "dbconn.php";

    $dayofmonth = $_POST['dayofmonth']; 
    $month = $_POST['month']; 
    $year = $_POST['year']; 
    $noslots = $_POST['noslots']; 

    $results = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO calender VALUES ('".$year."-".$month."-".$dayofmonth."','".$noslots."')");

    header('Location:calender.php'); 

    ?>
```